# Rest service in SpringBoot expects a nested object in JSON from GET request

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa, entities

I am using SpringBoot. I have two entities, Users and Role. For each user record I want to assign a role.

In my entities I already have the relationship and the database is built as I want.

When I see the service, it asks me for the Role object when I want to save the user. Am I right in wanting to create the User record? Or with @AutoWired can I add in my repository class the instance of Role and search it by id?

What do you recommend? I am still newbie with Rest services.

As an example, when invoking the create user service, the JSON it expects is the following:

```json
{ 
  "id": 1,
  "usuario": "JUANITO",
  "password": "*********",
  "correo": "algo@algo.com",
  "estado": "ACTIVO",
  "fecha": 12125368254,
  "rol": {
    "descripcion": "ADMIN",
    "estado": "ACTIVO",
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

I wish it was something similar to this:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "usuario": "JUANITO",
  "password": "*********",
  "correo": "algo@algo.com",
  "estado": "ACTIVO",
  "fecha": 12125368254,
  "rol": 1
}
```

That is, I do NOT want to create a new Role object, but use an existing one and assign it to my User record.

Answer (score 0):

> Or with @AutoWired can I add in my repository class the instance of Role and search it by id?

No, you can't simply autowire the instance of the given `Role` at runtime dynamically. If you want to be able to use the 2nd JSON you need to get the `Role` entity associated with the given ID, then set it in your `User` object and only then you can use your repository to save the `User`.